# About Inertial frame

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, inertial-frames

Does always a center of mass frame of reference is an inertial frame of reference? I mean suppose a system of particle is given in an external force field, then i think CM frame of this system is not an inertial frame. But sum of momentum of all particles is zero in CM frame even if external force is present. Please some one can tell me whether i am correct or not?

Answer (score 0):

> I mean suppose a system of particle is given in an external force field, then i think CM frame of this system is not an inertial frame.

Yes, you are correct. If the CM is accelerating, then a frame moving with the CM is a non-inertial frame.

> But sum of momentum of all particles is zero in CM frame even if external force is present.

The sum of momentum being $0$ doesn't determine if a frame is inertial or not. As a trivial example, think of a non-inertial frame looking at an empty system. As a little less trivial example, think of a non-inertial frame moving with a single accelerating particle. In the non-inertial frame, the particle has no momentum, yet the frame is still non-inertial.